# How to use dropdownlist to select on the calendar what the event to do

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use dropdownlist to select on the calendar what the event to do

if I select dropdownlist item is "Birthday" the calendar will show Birthday event
if I select dropdownlist item is "Party" the calendar will show Party event

Comment: Please show us some code and define more clearly what your are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

if i unencrypted correctly your question, you have to add a [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) (double click the combo box, or click on it then go to properties then events then select the SelectedIndexChanged) on your combo box and then you will have to change the date on the calendar using the [Calendar.SelectedDate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx) inside that event.